# Unable to edit custom block without administrator permissions

Tags: blocks, layout-builder

I created a content type "landingpage" and a user role "editor". I enabled layout builder for this content type and enabled the option to overwrite the the layout for individual pages.

As Admin I can easily add custom blocks to the layout and afterwards I*m able to edit those blocks oder delete them.

As Editor, however, though I a am able to add custom blocks, I neither can edit my own blocks nor am I able to remove them.

I granted the editor role following permissions:

- Admin blocks
- Custom block: Manage display
- Content - Landing page: Configure layout overrides for content that the user can edit.
- Create and edit custom blocks
- Manage Layout Builder Modal

Im using Drupal 8.9.14

Has anyone an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

To edit the blocks in layout builder, the user needs to have permission to use contextual links.